# How to stop ClamAV/Clamscan from hogging the CPU/ draining the battery in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: clamav

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon (i7/7th gen). The battery life has gone from awesome (6-9 hours) to appalling (<2 hours).

Using `top` & `sudo powertop` I could see that the majority of the load was coming from the `clanscan` service. It was using over 50% of my CPU.

I'm not sure why this is happening - I would think that antivirus software would be designed not to use over 50% of a (relatively) powerful CPU.

The only thing I could think of is that I do run [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/) - which is constantly sychronising files in a shared Google Drive. It could be that the coming & going of files is triggering Clamscan to constantly scan the file system?

For comparison turning off ClamAV & Insync dropped my base CPU usage from 66% to 8%.

I've got two questions:

1. Has anyone else experienced this behaviour from ClamAV/ Clamscan?
2. Is there a way I can stop ClamAV/ Clamscan hogging my CPU & draining my battery?

I suppose the another question is whether there are alternatives to Clamscan that don't attempt to cripple the machine they're on?

Comment: How about not run sync and clam when on battery?

Comment: @mikewhatever - is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed the Clam GUI `clamTk` and `clamtk-gnome`, (https://dave-theunsub.github.io/clamtk/), bring up the GUI, select the Scheduler icon, and set the desired scan frequency, or none at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal, you could do something like this:

```
$ sudo clamscan -ir -l /var/log/clamav.log --exclude-dir="^/proc/|^/sys/|^/dev/" --max-scansize=50M //.
```

It limits CPU hogging by excluding directories that are unlikely to contain problems and by limiting file size. Running it after-hours also helps:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*       3       *       *       1,3,5   clamscan -ir -l /var/log/clamav.log --exclude-dir="^/proc/|^/sys/|^/dev/" --max-scansize=50M //.
```

An additional fix (if the above is not enough): Limit the maximum resources a clamscan process can use. Add the following to cron:

```
cpulimit -l 30 -- clamscan -ir -l /var/log/clamav.log --exclude-dir="^/proc/|^/sys/|^/dev/" --max-scansize=50M //.
```

This limits the amount of CPU usage to 30% (or any other value that works for you).

See https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-with-cpulimit-on-ubuntu-linux for more details on cpulimit.